# MongoDB find distinct by substring

Tags: mongodb, distinct, substr

I searched MongoDB documentation and similar questions here, but found nothing, appreciate any help, URL, hint..etc.

I have a collection of picture data which looks something like this:

```
_id:613d39715c451ffa34ca792c
origPicFile:"C:\Users\Fadil\Pictures\2010\DSC05791.JPG"
created:"2021-09-11T18:19:13.652263"
.....
EXIF:
    ImageModel:"DSC-N2"
    EXIFDateTimeOriginal:"2010:01:15 18:27:18"
```

The datetime ranges between 1994-2021. and I am looking for all distnct years of pictures

could not find "distinct" with "substr".

To complicate things further, I want a distinct substr plus (either or), meaning if the EXIF does not have the EXIFDateTimeOriginal then I take the year from origPicFilename.

i.e. I am looking for something like this:

```
if EXIF.EXIFDateTime is populated then get the distinct of:
     $substr: [ "$EXIF.EXIFDateTimeOriginal", 0, 4 ]
else give me distinct 
     $substr: [ "$origPicFile", 24, 4 ]
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try an aggregation query to get distinct values - see the `$group` stage.  Also, aggregation queries support various operators to use the existing data and transform it to your needs - see aggregate string operators like `$substrCP`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I eventually did but as you can see in my answer below it does not solve the whole issue. but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

The closest I came up with to solve the problem is:

```
db.PICS.aggregate([
  { "$group": {"_id":  {"$substr": [ "$EXIF.EXIFDateTimeOriginal", 0, 4 ]}, "count": {"$sum":1}}},
  { "$unionWith": { "coll": "PICS", "pipeline": [ {"$group": {"_id":  {"$substr": [ "$origPicFile", 24, 4 ]}, "count": {"$sum":1}}} ] } },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "total": { "$sum": "$count" } } },
  { "$project": {"_id": 0, "Year": "$_id", "Total": "$total"}},
  {"$sort":{"Year":1}}
])
```

which ouputs something like:

```
[{'Total': 6425, 'Year': ''},
 {'Total': 61, 'Year': '0000'},
 {'Total': 33, 'Year': '1994'},
 {'Total': 27, 'Year': '1995'},
 {'Total': 2, 'Year': '1996'},
 {'Total': 18, 'Year': '1997'},
 {'Total': 55, 'Year': '1998'},
 {'Total': 5, 'Year': '1999'}]
```

As you can see it does not get rid of 0000 and empty year, adding a "$match" stage to do that did not work.
So for now this is good enough and filter the 0000 and empty years in the code.

Comment: _"...adding a "$match" stage to do that did not work."_ : You can add a match stage in the end to filter the unwanted Year data.